# How does changing the "size" of the infinitesimal $dx$ change the interpretation of the resulting integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

I recently asked a question ([During U-substitution, is the $du$ that we use as the infinitesimal in $\int f(u) \ du$ changing size?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280310/during-u-substitution-is-the-du-that-we-use-as-the-infinitesimal-in-int-fu)) and was explained that there is sort of a "freedom" with how one chooses to subdivide the area underneath a given curve so long as the way you define your dx (in the context of Riemann sum) will converge to zero as n→∞ .

This immediately made me realize that you could subdivide a given area under the curve an infinitely many number of ways (even "more so" when you consider that the subdivisions do not even have to be uniform).

As I understand it, these changes in subdivisions **do not alter the resulting value of the integral**. And perhaps that is where my misunderstanding arrives.

Consider the picture below:

[image: Infinitesimal Understanding]

In the first picture, we would have an integral of the following form: $\int_A^B f(x) d(x)$

In the second picture, we would have an integral of the following form: $\int_A^B f(x) 2dx$  (at least I believe that is how the notation would work)

My confusion is the following: using either one of these versions of uniform subdivisions will result in the same value. However, I feel like there must be a different interpretation that captures the fact that the subdivision for the lower graph is actually going to "fill up" the area under the curve more quickly.

Could someone please explain?

Edit 1: It seems like a clarification that I need in my question (based on below comments) is my misunderstanding of why a change in our “dx of choice” necessarily redefines the interval we are discussing. I do not see why I can’t change the subdivision without changing the interval.

Edit 2: As I know understand, the picture that I have is incorrect in that the bottom image should have its interval redefined to $2A$ and $2B$. However, I still do not understand why the change in interval demands that a corresponding change in subdivision must occur.

Comment: This is not really a different question. The confusion seems to stem from thinking of the $dx$ part of the notation as an independent mathematical object. In reality, you really have to consider the underlying Riemann sums (or their generalizations, as the answers to the other questions explain) if you want to modify the way the integral is computed. Those modifications are known to be consistent with the original value.—For your specific example: consider the change of variables $x=2w$, and think about how that affects all the parts of the integral, not just the $dx$ part.

Comment: I believe what you’re implying is that the interval therefore changes in accordance with the change of variable. However, that is not my question and therefore makes me think that I should change the notation from $2*dx$ to $d(2x)$. These mean fundamentally different things, correct?

Comment: After reading a few more things, I realize that $2dx$ and $d(2x)$ are equivalent. My question still remains, though. Namely, that I do not understand why the "subdivision strategy" needs to reflect the change in interval. If all subdivisions are approaching zero anyway, I feel like all values would be equivalent and therefore there shouldn't be ONE specifically (i.e. g$'(x)$ ) that needs to be used.

Comment: Correctly executed, the integral changes to $\int_{A/2}^{B/2}f(2x)\,2dx$ under this substitution.

Answer (score 0):

In the Riemann sum, if you widen the intervals , say from $\Delta x$ to $  2 \Delta x$, then the number of intervals is half, to cover the same interval in $x$, therefore the sum in the limit does not change.

If I got properly your comment, you are concerned with the doubt :
" up to which point I can modify the subdivision of the $x$ interval  from a standard linear (equal $\Delta x$) into an arbitrary subdivision
(let's call it non-linear), without altering the limit of the Riemann sum ?".

To that, I am going to answer to you just *intuitively* ; others more expert in the field might give a more rigorous answer.

[image: Riemann_Sum_1]

And the intuition is that given in the sketch: until the function that determines the partition is bi-jective
the limit of the sum will not change.
That is because, where you are taking smaller $\Delta x'_{\,k} $, you are taking more bars in the histogram,
so that the weighted sums $f(x'_{\,k}) \cdot \Delta x'_{\,k} $  and $f(x_{\,k}) \cdot \Delta x_{\,k} $
are going to coincide in the limit.

Comment: This is getting closer to the crux of my misunderstanding. My confusion, however, is that if all of these tiny little subdivisions are approaching zero, shouldn't I be able to use any size of "adjusted" subdivision (i.e. not just the $g'(x)$ adjustment)? The only analogy that I can think of to get around this is that it isn't necessarily about whether or not we "find the area under the curve"...the issue is whether or not the subdivision strategies "fill up" the area under the curve at the same time. (hopefully you understand what i mean)

Comment: So, to use my graphs as an example, if we were to fill up the interval "2A to 2B" with twice the "subdivision size" (i.e. $2dx$ )as we were to fill up the "A to B" interval with the unaltered subdivision size (i.e. $dx$) , if we started at the same time, they would both fill up at the exact same instance.

Comment: It would help if you correctly defined the subdivisions. You go from $x_i=A+i\,dx$ to $x_i=A+2i\,dx$, these are different points for the same index, and a different amount of points in the interval $[A,B]$.

Comment: You are aware that the integrals of the same integrand $f$ over $[A/2,B/2]$, $[A,B]$ and $[2A,2B]$ are all different?

Comment: If I change the bottom graph's interval to 2A and 2B (rather than A and B), then this would be correct, yes?

Comment: For the same “subdivision”, yes. But for different subdivisions, (i.e. different infinitesimals) they could be the same, right?

Comment: It seems like the “filling up” analogy I am making use of is effectively ensuring that the indices from f(u)du match up with the corresponding indices for f(g(x)g’(x)dx throughout the desired interval

Comment: @S.Cramer: ok, now I got your (crucial) point: i will extend my answer.